# .htaccess rewrite "app-domain.com/example.com" to "example.com"?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to .htaccess rewrite "http://app-domain.com/example.com?page=podcast" to "http://example.com/?page=podcast" ?

I am developing applications for multiple users, distinguished by /domain.com as their own page ID, and want users to be able to point their domain name to the same application server, compared to the /domain.com condition.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app-domain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/?page=podcast/ [R=302,L]
```

I've tried a lot of variants of this rule but I always get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of two rules: one to redirect the long URL variant, a second one to internally rewrite incoming requests using the short URL variant.

That might be a starting point for you:

```
# externally redirect https://app-domain.com/example.com/foo?bar to https://example.com/foo?bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+\.\w+)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1/%2 [QSA,L,R=301]

# internall rewrite https://example.com/foo?bar to /example.com/foo?bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?app-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(\w+\.\w+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

You can play around with that [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e1a95ecc-a1d1-44b9-9953-7b2dc91b03b0), if you like.

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents client side caching issues while testing. Nevertheless you should test using a fresh anonymous windows each time.

Such rules can be implemented in the central http server's virtual host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"), but that comes with a performance disadvantage, raised complexity and you have to enable the interpretation of such files first (see the documentation about the `AllowOverride` directive). Such a file would have to be placed in a `DocumentRoot` folder common to all virtual hosts (domains).